# How do you generate a list on excel based on a given criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to build something like a dashboard with couple of drop-downs, that would search a table and provide me a list, based on what I have selected. Please see below table:

[image: Table example]

So what I want is, when I select 'Not required' from one drop-down, and 'Doc 2' from another, it should give me a list of all the Systems that match this criteria.

I would really appreciate any help on this!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume the screenshot is your data table, and the two dropdowns for specifying the criteria are elsewhere.

This formula, filled down from B17 in the video below, lists the Systems matching the criteria:
    `=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$13,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$1:A$12)/(INDEX(B$2:H$13,,MATCH(C$18,B$1:H$1))=C$17),ROW()-16)),"")`

This is an array formula, and it must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

I hope this helps, and good luck.
**______________________________________________________________________________**

**How it works:** The inner `INDEX()` returns a whole column of the data table chosen with the "Doc" dropdown in `C$18`.  Then the equality `=C$17` returns an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values with `TRUE` in every position where a cell contains the choice in the `C$17` dropdown.

`ROW(A$1:A$12)` gives an array of the sequential numbers `{1;2;3;...12}`, and this is divided by the `TRUE/FALSE` array.

In arithmetic operations involving logical values, `TRUE` and `FALSE` are converted to 1's and 0's.  So the division gives an array of `#DIV/0!` errors for each `FALSE`, interspersed with the row numbers of each occurrence of the value from the dropdown.

This array is fed to the `AGGREGATE()` function which does the same thing that `SMALL()` would do (function=15), except it has an option to ignore errors (option=6). So `AGGREGATE()` ignores the `#DIV/0!` errors, and gives an array containing just the row numbers of the values from the C$17 dropdown, as the function is filled down.  This array is used as the `row-num`'s in another `INDEX()`, which returns a list of the Systems corresponding to those row numbers.

Finally, `IFERROR()` inserts a blank whenever `INDEX()` gives an error as it is filled down further than the number of values in it's list of row_nums.

I put this formula in row 17, so the last `ROW()-16` starts the list with the 1st row_num in the array.  So you should change the last "16" to one less than the row number where you have the formula.

Comment: Oh wow I did not expect such a comprehensive and detailed response! Really appreciate this Bandersnatch! I shall try this today or tomorrow and I will let you know how I get on.. Thanks again both for the solution and explaining how it works!

Comment: Sorry to be a bother but could you please let me have the spreadsheet you have created?

Comment: I've uploaded it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhs4adr2s2gl478/List%20Maker.xlsx?dl=0).  Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Don't click the "Open" button, that opens the workbook in Excel Online.  Next to the "Open" button are three dots (...) and under that menu is "Download".  They shouldn't be so damn secretive about that.  :-)

Comment: I just used your solution for something similar, that's awesome!!! Thank you very much @Bandersnatch